# Chart.js - change the scale background color of Radar type

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to change the scale background color of Radar type, as shown in the snap below. How to achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you have a "config" object containing your options/configurations inside your chart, do the following:

```
chart.config.options.scale.ticks.backdropColor = "black"; // "scale" is singular
chart.config.options.scale.ticks.display = true; // "scale" is singular
```